# Why can I use (almost) any type in a foreach over a list of unrelated interfaces?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, compiler-errors

With the first `foreach` in the below example, I'm sure it should throw a compilation error, but they build fine. Issues only occur at run time when it throws an invalid cast exception (as you'd expect):

```
public interface IState
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}

public class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}

public void Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<IState> states = new List<IState>();
    foreach (Dog dog in states) { } // Does not break in the compiler

    IEnumerable<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
    foreach (Dog dog in cats) { } // Obviously breaks in compiler
}
```

Why does this get passed the compiler? `Dog`is completely unrelated to `IState`, and if I tried to iterate through a list of `Cat` instead then the compiler will obviously catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is implicitly converting a cast from the element type to the type you've specified in the `foreach` statement.

So if you have an `IEnumerable<Foo>` and you use it as:

```
foreach (Bar bar in foos)
```

then that will insert a cast from `Foo` to `Bar`. This will compile if and only if that cast would normally be valid.

It *isn't* valid to cast from `Cat` to `Dog` because they're unrelated types. A `Cat` reference can *never* be valid as a `Dog` reference.

If *is* valid to cast from `IState` to `Dog` because it *could* be valid:

```
public class DogState : Dog, IState
{
    public int Id => 5;
    public string Description => "Dog state!";
}

IState state = new DogState();
Dog dog = (Dog) state; // Won't throw
```

In your collection example:

```
IEnumerable<IState> states = new List<IState> { new DogState() };
foreach (Dog dog in states)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I've got a dog state!");
}
```

Comment: [The specification for this behaviour is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements) - search for *local_variable_type* to find the pertinant information. It states that `If there is not an explicit conversion (Explicit conversions) from T (the element type) to V (the local_variable_type in the foreach statement), an error is produced and no further steps are taken.`

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense with those examples.